# Tableau Dashboard - top 15 filter not sorting correctly

Tags: sorting, filter, tableau-api

[sorted correct but not top 15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hcYb.png)

[sorted incorrectly but top 15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5X2j.png)

I have this dashboard and I want to show the top 15 stations on current year (2018) for delays/departures.

If I have the sort in the Columns, it sorts in the correct order, but it shows all of the stations.

If I put the Station in the filter for top 15, it somehow gets sorted incorrectly.

My formulas are 
2018 rank = if [Year] = 2018 then [Delay Measure] else 0 end
2018 ranks = [2018 rank]/departures_count

Answer (score 2):

Make [Month] a **context** filter, by right clicking on it on the filter shelf and choosing “Add to Context”

Then Tableau will first apply the [Month] filter and then apply the top 15 stations filter upon those results. Otherwise, the filters are independent and you are filtering to the top 15 stations over all months, then just showing the data for a selected month.

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there, you need to combine approaches

Firstly you filter to get the top N from the column pill Station. So click --> Filter --> Top N field

[image]

Then once you have done that you'll only be showing the top n results in your report

Next we can sort these top 15:

Click on column pill --> Sort --> Descending --> Your sorting field

[image]

---

Instead of choosing a number to filter the number of stations, it's a nice idea to give users the option by using a parameter. Then in the Top N you can change it to your newly created integer parameter:

[image]

Comment: It didn't work; it still looks like the incorrect version. The incorrect version was created from the correct version by just adding a filter to Station, so it was already sorted.

Comment: So for the column in your report, you've added the Station dimension, then you filtering by getting the Top N by the 2018 measure? Once you have that, then you click on the Station pill in columns and sort it. Try doing it from the start as opposed to amending something that doesn't work

Comment: It doesn't work, sorting first than filtering or filtering first than sorting. The top 15 isn't the correct top 15. If you look at the photos, the 15th station should be MCO, but with the top 15 filter on it's MFE.